# Unity: 'JsonSerializer' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to JSonSerialier in Unity which I used in a stand alone Console project. However this fails on Unity.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int level {get; set;}
    public float timeElapsed {get; set;}
    public string playerName {get; set;}
}
```

Then in some function of the code I do this:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.level = 1;
myObject.timeElapsed = 47.5f;
myObject.playerName = "Dr Charles Francis";
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(myObject));
```

This works perfectly fine in a code that I run using "dotnet run" on Windows.

However when I use this in one of the Unity Scripts, I get the following error:

```
'JsonSerializer' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

So how can I use JsonSerializer in Unity?

Comment: Which library is this? System.Text.Json? How are you including it in your project?

Comment: Hi. Yes when I create the standalone C# application I only inlucde (using System.Text.Json) Should I include it in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

The `JsonSerializer` seems not to work properly with Unity. I have switched to using `Newtonsoft.Json` instead.

What you can do to achieve the desired result is:

Define your class as you did already:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int level {get; set;}
    public float timeElapsed {get; set;}
    public string playerName {get; set;}
}
```

Add the import to your file/class where you are using the JSON:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

And inside your processing class use the following method:

```
private void SendJson(MyClass _event)
{
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_event);
    byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
}
```

The json string or jsonBytes array can be used to e.g. send it to a server.

I hope this helps - please let me know if I can be of any further help.

Comment: Method parameters should not have names with underscore prefixes btw. To use keywords  (like `event`) as identifiers in C# you prefix them with `@`, i.e. `@event`.

Comment: You should explain why you use a third party solution instead of the built-in [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not familiar with Unity, but I looked at their docs and I see that Unity's `JsonUtility` is very lacking in features to allow you to control the de/serialziation - for example, I don't see any support for immutable JSON DTO types using `[JsonConstructor]`-based deserialization - also, if you're using an existing DTO library with Json.NET's attributes then using `JsonUtility` won't work for you.

Comment: @UnholySheep I agree with Dai if you have a look at the "Supported types" section of the documentation you linked it states that only a very limited number of types are supported.

Comment: Yes. I have effectively solved the issue by using Newtonsoft library. JsonUtility did not support the actuall strcture I needed to serialize/deserialize which included dictionaries fo base types and of custom built classes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Newtonsoft JSON library already suggest in the other answer, for simple things there's also the Unity-native [JsonUtility.ToJson](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html):

```
string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(someClass);
```

You do get floating point accuracy [oddities](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1530474/jsonutility-serializes-floats-with-way-too-many-di.html) though, e.g. `0.7f` may turn into `0.699999988079071` when serialized, and Newtonsoft fixes that.